# Strip whitespace from CSV column and overwrite column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have the below csv file:

| Year | MonthLong |
| --- | --- |
| 1984 | December |
| 1984 | January |

After 'December   ' there is some white space reoccurring throughout the dataframe.

Can anyone help me figure out how to strip this and save it? Haven't used .strip before and I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have imported your csv as a pandas dataframe, you can:

```
df['MonthLong'] = df['MonthLong'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())
```

Comment: Yep, I'm using pd.read_csv but for some reason getting AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: Sorry, the .str is not necessary

df['MonthLong'] = df['MonthLong'].apply(lambda x: x.strip())

Comment: damn, getting this error now 'Series' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Sorry there was an extra strip, thank you Giovanni, I need to learn what lambda does!